# Должен ли я минифицировать мой css и javascript код в Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Javascript код веб сайта находятся в директории pulbic, должен ли я минифицировать свой код для  готовой версии сайта ?

Нужно ли мне свои javascript и css коды хранить в папке resources а результат минификации в public ?

Если есть ссылки или информация  буду рад посмотреть.

Answer (score 1):

Минифицировать однозначно надо.

Либо так, либо рядом. Например:

```
- public
 |- style.css
 |- style.min.css
 |- script.js
 |- script.min.js
```

Для небольшого проекта подойдет.
Если исходников много, лучше, конечно, держать исходники отдельно, и собирать их в public